# Does there exist a function a subset of $\Bbb R $ to $\Bbb R$ with dense set of removal discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x) = x \sin(1/x) $ for all $x$ non zero. We can remove the discontinuity at $x=0$ by simply define $f(0) =0$, again we can define a function help of $f$ such that function have two points of removal discontinuity, so we can construct a function whose domain inside $\mathbb R$ such that the function had finite points of removal discontinuity

Now my question is

1. Can we construct a function infinite points of removal discontinuity?
   //
2. Does there exist a function having a dense set of points of removal discontinuity?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but what about $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that any point in $B$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}\setminus B$, then define $f(x)=1$ if $x\notin B$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in B$. For example $B=\mathbb{Q}$. It seems weird to me to talk about removable discontinuities that are not isolated though, it feels a little arbitrary.

Comment: @Jose27: I think there's a little subtlety here. The function you've defined does not have a removable discontinuity *anywhere*. The following is true: You can redefine the function on $B$ to make it continuous everywhere, but individually, no point of $B$ is a point of removable discontinuity.

Comment: The function you defined is continuous so why do you say about discontinuity?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{ if }x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\\
{1\over q} & \mbox{ if $x$ is rational and $x={p\over q}$ in lowest terms.}
\end{cases}$$

[image: Image from that'smath.com]

The above image was taken from [thatsmath.com](https://thatsmaths.com/2012/10/25/the-popcorn-function/).

This function has the property that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}F(x)=0$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and consequently it is continuous on the irrationals and removably-discontinuous on each rational. This function has many names; I learned it as "the popcorn function," but wikipedia gives prominence to the name "[Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)."

(To be precise, I'm interpreting "$F$ has a removable discontinuity at $c$" as "$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}F(x)$ exists but is not $F(c)$.")

Comment: In case you're interested, I posted a lot of information about this function, which I learned many years ago as the "ruler function", in [this 13 December 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/m9SfPUdr4I4/m/kcpzwLqqtJUJ) (see also the follow-up comments-and-corrections posts). Presently I have several loose leaf notebooks filled with material on this topic that contain several times as many items as cited in that 2006 post, but I don't know whether I'll be up to posting it all anytime soon. I do have an annotated bibliography I maintain (currently about 30 pages), however.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ooh neat! I'd love to see that bibliography, is it available?